# List of potential syntax errors for solr query syntax?

Tags: solr, syntax-error

I'm trying to see if there is a comprehensive listing of syntax errors for solr. My goal is to create a function that "cleans up" the front-end user's query so that it doesn't cause syntax errors.

So far I've found two errors:

#### EOF

If the query ends in AND, OR, NOT, etc. in upper case, throws an EOF error.
**Fix**: lowercase query (since the query is set to be non-case-sensitive anyway)

#### Unidentified Field Information

If the query contains a colon, as in "Start of Long Academic Title: Witty Subtitle Here".
**Fix**: replace all instances of `:` with a space.

I'm hoping that's all the problems I need to fix, but if there are any other solr syntax errors I should be aware of and control for, that would be very useful!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is any comprehensive list of syntactic errors, but here are some, that we took care of:

```
1) encoding issues: special characters like %, & etc should not be
passed as it is as they may ruin the whole query

2) cases of two asterisks together: ** may cause infinite loops or
put the system down to its knees, if leading and trailing wildcards
are accepted. Case when a search term is just one asterisk isn't
allowed in our system either

3) (optionally) for boolean queries ensure that opening and closing
brackets match

4) strip the punctuation, but do it with care, e.g. if U.S. turns
into US, then to ensure findability (recall matters to us), we make
sure same happens during the tokenization. Also we identify urls and
don't remove punctuation from them

5) some errors may relate to malformed proximity operators (like
near, ~), e.g. we don't allow them to be nested or boolean operators
inside them
```

Also I would say, that some syntactic errors can be controlled through the light of the syntax that you have defined yourself for your users. That is don't allow them what you don't want to allow them. This also forms some sort of search contract between your users and your application. It is also good to provide some tooltip-like information that will tell the users what typical syntax can be used for what purpose.